# Installig Vertica on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vertica

Is it possible to install Vertica on Ubuntu 12.04 (not server)?

While installing I receive this error:

```
UnsupportedOSException: (127.0.0.1) This version of ubuntu is unsupported.
```

Comment: What version of Vertica are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

From the supported operating system list, Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 Long Term Support (LTS) versions are supported.

- [Supported Platforms Document](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/PDF/HP_Vertica_7.1.x_Supported_Platforms.pdf)

If you are continuing to get errors, you may want to look at these possible workarounds:

- [Workaround: Vertica Error: This version of Debian or Ubuntu is unsupported](http://www.davewentzel.com/content/workaround-vertica-error-version-debian-or-ubuntu-unsupported)
- [vertica installation on ubuntu](https://community.vertica.com/vertica/topics/vertica_installation_on_ubuntu)